# Unable to spoof MacOS level in order to install printer driver for Canon i950

Tags: drivers, printer

I booted into single user mode (CMD + s). As the first attempt failed due to insufficient authority to edit the SystemVersion.plist, I tried again using "su" to switch to root, but this didn't allow me to edit the file either:-

su: Sorry

apfs_vfsop_mount:1171 Updating mount from /dev/disk1s5 to read/write mode is not allowed mount: / failed with 77

I was trying to edit SystemVersion.plist to change Product(User)VisibleVersion to "10.5.0 or later" as expected by the Canon driver installer (I'm actually on 10.15.7).

Answer (score 0):

Current [Canon i950 drivers](https://canondriversupport.com/canon-i950-series-driver/) are valid from v. 10.7 through 10.13. Though that driver is not certified for 10.15, it *might* have a better chance at being installed, with or without that hack.

A workaround is to to create a virtual machine with Mac OS v. 10.13 and install the driver on that... with it being a nuisance to print, requiring files be placed in a shared folder, and the VM started. <sub>*sigh*</sub>.

Finally, you *could* contact [Canon Support](https://canondriversupport.com/contact-us/), though likely they'd prefer you buy a newer printer than provide updated drivers for a 20 year old model, though it may work well.

Comment: I tried the driver on the cited Canon site but that required PowerPC (I have Intel).